# Serving mp3 files as part of a npm package

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, mp3, babel-loader

I created a NPM package that uses `mp3` files, and plays them using [**howler.js**](https://howlerjs.com/).

When I install the package as a dependency on another project, I can't seem to play the files from the node_modules folder.

I have tried using *babel* alone and *webpack* with *babel*, *file-loader*, *url-loader*.

**Code for requiring files**

```
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist/public/Media/' + note.instrument + '/' + 'FF_' + notes['b'][notes[note.lang].indexOf(note._note)] + note._octave + '.mp3')
    sounds.set(key, new Howl({
        src: [filePath]
    }))
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
}
```

**Error**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'file:///dist/public/Media/Piano/FF_C1.mp3' from origin 'null' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported
>   for protocol schemes

**How can I bundle and resolve static assets for use in another project?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering, i eventually solved it by creating a Rest API that serves the files and fetching them when needed.